# Updating lightweight-charts candlestick series results in Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'year')

Tags: javascript, lightweight-charts

When running `update` on candlestick series I'm getting `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'year')`. Data is prepared the same way it was for `setData` and look like this: `[{time: 1649068320, open: '0.15721000', high: '0.15776000', low: '0.15710000', close: '0.15760000'}]`.

What am I missing here?

I tried to update with same data as was used with setData and got same error.

Also tried to prepare data this way:
`var time = moment(item.openTime); time = { year: time.year(), month: time.month(), day: time.day(), hour: time.hour(), minute: time.minute(), second: time.second(), }` and `var time = new Date(item.openTime)`

**Minimum steps to reproduce**

```
import { createChart } from 'lightweight-charts';
var container = document.getElementById('price-chart');
const chart = createChart(container, {height:300});
chart.applyOptions({
    timeScale: {
        visible: true,
        timeVisible: true,
    },
});
const candlestick = chart.addCandlestickSeries();
candlestick.setData([{time: 1649102700, open: '3.39110000', high: '3.39130000', low: '3.38610000', close: '3.38670000'}]);
candlestick.update([{time: 1649102700, open: '3.39110000', high: '3.39130000', low: '3.38610000', close: '3.38670000'}]);
```

Answer (score 3):

`update` takes single object. so instead of

```
candlestick.update([{time: 1649102700, open: '3.39110000', high: '3.39130000', low: '3.38610000', close: '3.38670000'}]);
```

it should be

```
candlestick.update({time: 1649102700, open: '3.39110000', high: '3.39130000', low: '3.38610000', close: '3.38670000'});
```

Also:

- You cannot use `update` on past data. So when scrolling backwards, you need to use `setData`
- when setting data, array must be in chronological order or you will get `Uncaught Error: Value is null`.